# Sort Elasticsearch buckets on same attributes as documents

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, aggregation

There is a way to sort documents by multiple attributes. 
I want to sort aggregated buckets in same way by same attributes. Is this possible?

Here are my sample documents:

```
    curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/_bulk?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: 
application/json' -d'
    { "index" : { "_index" : "cars", "_type" : "cars", "_id" : "1" } }
    { "make":"BMW", "series":"3er", "doorCount": 4}
    { "index" : { "_index" : "cars", "_type" : "cars", "_id" : "2" } }
    { "make":"BMW", "series":"3er", "doorCount": 5}
    { "index" : { "_index" : "cars", "_type" : "cars", "_id" : "3" } }
    { "make":"Opel", "series":"Astra", "doorCount": 2}
    { "index" : { "_index" : "cars", "_type" : "cars", "_id" : "4" } }
    { "make":"Opel", "series":"Omega", "doorCount": 2}
    '
```

Here I'm setting fielddata to true to be able to aggregate:

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/cars/_mapping/cars?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "properties": {
    "make": { 
      "type":     "text",
      "fielddata": true
    },
    "series": { 
      "type":     "text",
      "fielddata": true
    }
  }
}
'
```

Here is the query aggregating buckets:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/cars/cars/_search?pretty' -d'
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggregations" : {
    "CARS" : {
      "terms" : {
        "script" : {
          "inline" : "doc[\"make\"].value + \"_\" + doc[\"series\"].value",
          "lang" : "painless"
        }      
      },
      "aggregations" : {
        "make" : {
          "terms" : { "field" : "make"}
        },
        "series" : {
          "terms" : { "field" : "series" }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
'
```

Any idea how to sort buckets by make and series ?

Answer (score 0):

First off, you probably want to specify `make` and `series` to be of type [`keyword`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html) instead of `text` because it doesn't need to be analyzed (you want exact matches on these fields).

What does your output look like? When I tried it, it seems to be sorted correctly.

```
  [
    {
      "key": "bmw_3er",
      "doc_count": 2,
      "series": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
        "buckets": [
          {
            "key": "3er",
            "doc_count": 2
          }
        ]
      },
      "make": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
        "buckets": [
          {
            "key": "bmw",
            "doc_count": 2
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "key": "opel_astra",
      "doc_count": 1,
      "series": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
        "buckets": [
          {
            "key": "astra",
            "doc_count": 1
          }
        ]
      },
      "make": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
        "buckets": [
          {
            "key": "opel",
            "doc_count": 1
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "key": "opel_omega",
      "doc_count": 1,
      "series": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
        "buckets": [
          {
            "key": "omega",
            "doc_count": 1
          }
        ]
      },
      "make": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
        "buckets": [
          {
            "key": "opel",
            "doc_count": 1
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
```

Comment: I want to add to my query kind of `sort`  parameter like when I'm sorting normal documents:     `"sort" : [
        { "series" : "desc" },
        { "make" : "asc" }
    ]`, so that order buckets will be sorted by series first and by make second